# Cannot extract response body to set environment variable

Tags: json, testing, postman

I have response body from POST method like below:

```
{
    "status": {
        "error": false,
        "code": 200,
        "message": "Login success"
    },
    "result": {
        "data": {
            "name": "vv",
            "email": "gg@gmail.com",
            "session_key": "xxx"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I want to extract that session key to add in the environment variable.
I used this code:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("session", jsonData.sesssion_key);
```

But on the environment variable still return with "undefined" value
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("session", jsonData.result.data.session_key);
```

you need to provide the exact path to get the value of session_key.

I didnt test it , but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, it worked now with this solution 
`var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("session", jsonData.result.data.session_key);`